# Logitech mouse with unifying receiver has instant connection issues

Tags: mouse, battery, logitech

My mouse is Logitech MX Ergo. I use Logitech unifying receiver. When mouse is connected to the power cable  and charging the issue does not appear.

When the mouse is not charging, then at random points it loses connection and reconnects immediately, but it makes the mouse unusable for a little while. Moust button presses are lost, mouse does not respond to movement etc

In logs it appears

```
UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
```

Upower shows

```
[10:03:42.817]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/unknown_0003o046Do406Fx000A
  native-path:          /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-8/3-8:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0008/0003:046D:406F.000A
  vendor:               Logitech, Inc.
  serial:               5BCD2B92
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Παρ 10 Ιαν 2020 10:03:42 πμ EET (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       none
    icon-name:          'battery-missing-symbolic'
```

Any ideas where to start looking for the problem?

My dist version is
4.15.0-72-generic 16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP

Comment: I have the same problem and it is driving me mad. This is with Logitech Performance MX and Logitech M705 mice.
Different from your diagnostics I get no output from upower for these mice. It used to work fine before the weekend, with battery status shown in the XFCE panel.

Comment: Did you charge the device? I think i saw it twice after full charge of the device. After a while it stops. Maybe it has to do something with the battery level (when high).

Comment: My Logitech K800 keyboard and MX Mouse have been working fine for years. Last month or so I've noticed these messages and upower no longer reports battery status.

Comment: I had a similar issues as you described. But I figured that those issues disappear if I use a USB Port on the other side of the device. It might sound stupid but is it possible that e.g. the wifi card interferes when it's close by? The only other difference I can think of is possibly a difference at USB 2 vs 3 ports.